Expected value of stopping time of non symmetric random walk$E[\tau_{a,b}]$ is finite
Suppose we have a random walk $S_n$ that increases by $1$ with probability $p \ne \frac{1}{2}$ and decreases by $1$ with probability $1-p$. And let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$.
How can I show that the expected value of $\tau_{a,b} := \inf \{n \ge 0: S_n \in \{-a,b\}\}$ ist finite.
In lecture it was stated that this is easy to see, however I do not know where to start proving this. Any help would be appreciated.

You can adapt the proof I gave in this answer.

You mean: how to compute the expected value, right?

@user007 Have you studied Markov chains? Do you know about recurrent and transient states?

@lonzaleggiera I have not learned about it yet

@MikeEarnest I am sorry my previous comment was misleading. It should be like stated in the post, to show that it is finite

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4992096/finite-exit-time-on-random-walks-on-a-b/

Assume WLOG that $p\ge 1/2$.
Divide up the random walk up until $\tau_{a,b}$ into phases, where each phase has $a+b$ steps. Suppose there exists a phase where all $a+b$ steps were to the right. Then the random walk will certainly hit $b$ during that phase, no matter where in the interval $(-a,b)$ the walk started during that phase. This shows that during each phase, there is a probability of at least $p^{a+b}>0$ that the random walk hits $b$ during that phase.
Let $X$ be the number of phases it takes to see $a+b$ right moves in a row. $X$ has finite expectation, as it is a geometric random variable. Since $\tau_{a,b}\le X$, this means $\tau_{a,b}$ has finite expectation has well.

Thank you. I like that solution
