Finite exit time on random walks on $[-a,b]$
Take $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be iid random variables in $L^1$ that are not identically null. If $S_n$ is the associated random walk commencing at 0 and $T_{a,b} = inf\{n \in \mathbb{N}: S_n \notin [-a,b] \}$ prove that $\mathbb{E}[T_{a,b}]$ is finite.
The item before this exercise defined $T_{b} = inf\{n \in \mathbb{N}: S_n > b] \}$ and required proof that $\mathbb{E}[T_{b}]$ is not finite when $\mathbb{E}[X_1]= 0 $ , which I was able to prove using Doob`s maximal inequality, however in this case I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is $E(X_{1})=0$? If yes then are there any assumptions about $X_{1}$ having finite variance?

Since $X_1$ is non-null, there must exist $\epsilon>0$ such that either

$\mathbb P(X_1>\epsilon)>0$, or

$\mathbb P(X_1<-\epsilon)<0$.


WLOG, the former occurs.
Let $N=\lceil (b+a)/\epsilon\rceil$. I claim that, for every $k\in \mathbb N$,
$$
\mathbb P(T_{a,b}>kN)\le \Big(1-\mathbb P(X_1>\epsilon)^N\Big)^k\tag1
$$
To see this, take the first $kN$ steps of the process, and break them into $k$ blocks, each consisting of $N$ consecutive steps. In order for $\{T_{a,b}>kN\}$ to occur, during each of these blocks, it must not be the case that $\{X_n>\epsilon\}$ occurred for each $n$ in the block (otherwise, we would move a total distance of $\epsilon\cdot \lceil (b+a)/\epsilon\rceil > b+a$ to the right during the block, which certainly make you exit the interval).
Finally, use the expression
$$
\mathbb E[T_{a,b}]=\sum_{t=0}^\infty\mathbb P(T_{a,b}>t)
$$
combined with $(1)$ to upper bound $\mathbb E[T_{a,b}]$ by a sum of $N$ geometric series. You will also need the fact that $\mathbb P(T_{a,b}>t)$ is a decreasing function of $t$, so that $\mathbb P(T_{a,b}>kN+r)\le \mathbb P(T_{a,b}>kN)$, for each $r\in \{0,\dots,N-1\}$.

(+1). But I am confused as to where does this method fail when applying it to the one one sided stopping time $T_{a}$ for $a>0$? i.e. say for example we take the SSRW on $\Bbb{Z}$. Then clearly $P(X_{1}>\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$. But still, $E(T_{a})=\infty$.

My logic does not apply to the one-sided case. Your proofs are rigorous; the only problem with them is that they are needlessly complex. There is no need to provide a separate argument for finite/infinite variance variables, as my method shows.

@Mr.GandalfSauron The comments chain is getting too long, so I created a chat room where we can discuss this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156030/finite-exit-time-for-random-walk-on-interval

$Z_{n}:=S_{n}-nE(X_{1})$ is a martingale. (i.e. the walk with steps $Y_{k}=X_{k}-E(X_{k})$.
Suppose that $E(X_{1})\neq 0$. Consider the martingale $(Z_{n\wedge T_{a,b}})$. You have $E(S_{n\wedge T_{a,b}}))=E(n\wedge T_{a,b})$ due to the Martingale property.
But $n\wedge T_{a,b}$ is an increasing sequence of random variables which converges to $T_{a,b}$ almost surely. Thus the Monontone Convergence Theorem tells you that $\lim_{n}E(n\wedge T_{a,b})=E(T_{a,b})$ (regardless of whether it is finite or not).
But as $E(n\wedge T_{a,b})=E(S_{n\wedge T_{a,b}})\leq \max(|a|,|b|)$ uniformly in $n$, you have that $E(T_{a,b})$ is finite.
If $E(X_{1})=0$, we'll assume that $Var(X_{1})<\infty$. then consider the Martingale $Z_{n}=S_{n}^{2}-\sigma^{2}n$ where $\sigma^{2}=Var(X_{1})$.
Then again, you have that $(Z_{n\wedge T_{a,b}})$ is a martingale such that $E(S_{n\wedge T_{a,b}}^{2})=\sigma^{2}E(T_{a,b}\wedge n)$. But again due to Monotone Convergence Theorem, $E(T_{a,b}\wedge n)\to E(T_{a,b})$ and as $|S_{n\wedge T_{a,b}}^{2}|\leq \max(a^{2},b^{2})$, you have that $E(T_{a,b})<\infty$
Note:- The intuitive reason for the assumption $Var(X_{1})<\infty$ is that it is reductive to assume $|X_{1}|$ is too large of a random variable. i.e. if $|X_{1}|>\min(|a|,|b|)$, then the walk will get out of the interval within the first step with positive probability. So some sort of decay of the tail of $X_{1}$ has to be assumed). So now, some truncation argument by taking the step sizes to be atmost $2\max(|a|,|b|)$ will lead to the same scenario as does with assuming finite variance which obviously is a more general condition.

Here is the full proof of the case of non-finite variance using truncation.
In case say $Var(X_{1})=\infty$ then we proceed by truncation.
$$P(\tau_{a,b}>N)=P\bigg(T_{a,b}>N\,,\,\bigcap_{i=1}^{N}\{|X_{i}|\leq 2(a+b)\}\bigg)\\+P\bigg(T_{a,b}>N\,,\,|X_{i}|>2(a+b)\text{for some } i=1,2,...,N\bigg) $$
Now note that in the second case, if there exists some $i<N$ such that $|X_{i}|>2(a+b)$, then obviously $T_{a,b}\leq N$. To see this take $i$ to be the first time such that $|X_{i}|>2(a+b)$. Then, as $|S_{i-1}|\leq \max(a,b)$, we will have that $|S_{i}|=|S_{i-1}+X_{i}|>\max(a,b)$ and hence $T\leq i$. So the probability of the second event is $0$.
So we need only focus on the first case. Now note that conditioned on the event that $\bigg\{T_{a,b}>N\,,\,\bigcap_{i=1}^{N}\{|X_{i}|\leq 2(a+b)\}\bigg\}$.
Consider the random walk $S_{n}'$, defined by $S_{0}'=0$ and $S_{n}'=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{n}'$ where $Y_{k}'$ are iid such that $Y_{k}'=X_{k}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{|X_{k}|\leq 2(a+b)}$. The advantage is that now $Y_{k}'$ have finite variance.
Now see that $P\bigg\{T_{a,b}>N\,,\,\bigcap_{i=1}^{N}\{|X_{i}|\leq 2(a+b)\}\bigg\}=P(T_{a,b}'>N)$ where $T_{a,b}'=\inf\{n:|S_{n}'|\notin[-a,b]\}$ . Now $\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}P(T_{a,b}'>N)=E(T_{a,b}')$.
But from the case of assuming finite variance, we already have that $E(T_{a,b}')<\infty$ and thus $\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}P(T_{a,b}'>N)<\infty$.
This shows that $\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}P(T_{a,b}>N)<\infty$ and hence $E(T_{a,b})<\infty$.
